# Uninstalling default VBoxGuestAdditions on Debian

Tags: debian, virtualbox

When I ran `sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` I got the following warning message:

```
You appear to have a version of the VBoxGuestAdditions software
on your system which was installed from a different source or using a
different type of installer.  If you installed it from a package from your
Linux distribution or if it is a default part of the system then we strongly
recommend that you cancel this installation and remove it properly before
installing this version. If this is simply and older or a damaged
installation you may safely proceed.
```

How do I uninstall the VBoxGuestAdditions that was a default part of Debian?

Edit:

After reading and trying out jw013's answer, I suspected that maybe I just didn't know the proper package names. I did a bit more searching, and found out that I can see the list of packages installed by running `dpkg -l`. So I ran

```
dpkg -l | grep virtualbox
```

then I got

```
ii   virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms ...
ii   virtualbox-ose-guest-utils ...
ii   virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 ...
```

Then I removed each manually by running

```
apt-get remove virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms virtualbox-ose-guest-utils virtualbox-ose-guest-x11
```

So far it looks like that might be the solution, though it's weird because when I run the command it wants to install 38 new packages, most of them with xserver related stuff.

Edit2:

I tried the above with a fresh install (reasonably minimal install -- used the businesscard.iso with nothing marked when tasksel came up) then followed the directions [here](http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-debian/), and everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's hard to tell what is going on if you can't remember or do not know where your old install of guest additions came from.

Do you have [`virtualbox-guest-additions`](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=guest%20additions) installed?  You can uninstall it by running (as a superuser)

```
apt-get remove virtualbox-guest-additions
```

If that's not it, I would recommend trying to follow the [instructions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) at the VirtualBox website.  Since it appears you already have an old version of the guest additions installed, try the uninstallation instructions:

```
sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall
```

Comment: Is 'uninstall' supposed to be 'remove'?

Comment: @math4tots yes you are right.  That's what I get for typing without thinking, doh!

Comment: I just tried it right now, and I got "Virtual packages like 'virtualbox-guest-additions' can't be removed"

Comment: I think the guest additions came with a fresh install. I set up another install of Debian with "debian-6.0.4-i386-businesscard.iso", this time with everything unchecked when tasksel came up, and I still got with GA

Comment: @math4tots hmm that's strange.  It's not installed on my system, and it seems unlikely that the installer would behave differently in a VM.  Did you get the latest version of guest additions installed correctly at least?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I've only tested folder sharing, but the installer had no complaints. On the other hand, I think the installer might behave differently in a VM. I used to use Zenix which would read "not in a vm" or something like that in red letters every time it would boot. Currently I have Ubuntu installed on a physical machine, and it didn't have GA pre-installed. Of course, it could just have been just stripped from Ubuntu, but it might be a hint.

Comment: I came across this and tried your solutions, however, neither worked for me. I'm running a Debian 6.0.5 in a VBox VM on a Windows 7 Host OS. I installed it with the netinst.iso and unchecked everything on installation, to install just the basic system.

Comment: Got the same message on Linux Mint 15, without having (wittingly) installed VirtualBox Additions from any other source yet. Was it bundled with Mint? The software manager shows that virtualbox-guest-dkms, -utils and -x11 were installed.

Answer (score 12):

Here's how I did it just now, after everything above failed...

`sudo bash /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*/uninstall.sh`

Comment: Knowing the location helps when you cannot mount the CD-rom for whatever reason.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me -

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox*
```

Source: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=65539

And this explains the problem -

> Note that some Linux distributions already come with all or part of the VirtualBox Guest Additions. You may choose to keep the distribution's version of the Guest Additions but these are often not up to date and limited in functionality, so we recommend replacing them with the Guest Additions that come with VirtualBox. The VirtualBox Linux Guest Additions installer tries to detect existing installation and replace them but depending on how the distribution integrates the Guest Additions, this may require some manual interaction. It is highly recommended to take a snapshot of the virtual machine before replacing pre-installed Guest Additions.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
apt-get autoremove virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms \
        virtualbox-ose-guest-utils virtualbox-ose-guest-x11
```

This does remove the xorg packages though.

Comment: Autoremove should not be necessary.

Comment: I like to remove all that isn't used/dependencies:)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and after trying the above options I had to delete the below file

vmbox-uninstall-guest-additions
from /usr/sbin directory

and then I ran the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run from the Guest Addition drive and it successfully worked for me.