# How to list uninstalled but not purged packaged?

Tags: apt

I uninstalled tons of package with `apt` and always used `remove`.

Knowing I won't ever use them, and I worry about polluting my system with old config files, how can I purge all of them? The `apt purge <package-name>` command requires me to know what I want to purge, and I don't remember everything.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68621/70524

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple way to do it is

```
dpkg -l | grep ^rc
```

This lists all (semi)installed packages, lines in list starts with state, rc means that the desired state is "remove" and the status is "conf-files".

If you want only package names:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: thank you ! It's a shame apt doesn't have an option for that